# How to Retrieve Windows 10 key?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-installation, windows-activation

I have Windows 7 copy that I upgraded for free Windows 10 a few years back. My SSD is getting too small to I want to swap it with a new SSD.

I want to do a complete wipe and install everything fresh instead of trying to make a backup and restoring it on the new SSD.

When I go to activation settings I see

> Windows is activated with a digital license to your Microsoft account.

I am not sure where I can actually get my key and how to get a copy of windows that will bootup before startup so I can install it on my SSD that won't have anything on it.

Answer (score 3):

If it is only your SSD that you replace, you can reinstall windows without a problem. It will automatically activate. The key is stored on the Microsoft Server along with a hardware ID. This ID will still work if most of your system remains the same.

If you want to be absolutely sure (but this is not necessary), you can enter your Windows 7 key that you upgraded with. You can also do this after the installation, if windows somehow does not activate your install.

During the installation, when it asks for a key, just press the skip button and continue the installation.

I perform an installation on a weekly basis and only seldomly do I have trouble, usually only when to much hardware has changed, but never when a harddisk was replaced.

Comment: In case it helps: I've read somewhere that the very latest Windows 10 does not show the "skip" button, unless you disable the network (say: unplug the ethernet cable or power down your WiFi modem) at that stage.

Comment: OK that's good to know and how to I get a bootable version? Can I make that from my computer or can I download that somewhere to put on a usb stick?

Comment: To add a bit more info - it's actually your motherboard that is used as the hardware ID. You can replace literally everything else and still use the same license key

Comment: Yep all I am doing is harddrive so I should be ok. I also found Media Creation Tool but I need to find 8gb of free space lol.

Comment: The media creation tool is indeed what you need. @Arjan I install Windows 10 regularly, even the latest version and I have not found anything that makes me think the skip button is gone, and I usually install with a network cable attached. But most of the time I do not need a license key as the devices I install have them embedded so the setup automatically detects this. Good to know at least, so I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Also, you could technically clone your harddisk to the SSD and then in windows simply reset your installation to reinstall. No need to create an install medium that way.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was confused with [Confirmed: Windows 10 Setup Now Prevents Local Account Creation](https://www.howtogeek.com/442609/confirmed-windows-10-setup-now-prevents-local-account-creation/).

Comment: @Arjan even that is not true. It just is a bit more obscure. You have to press a few nearly invisible no's and the setup will attempt to make you create a live account, but you can still use a local account. I do it basically on every install I do. EDIT: oh, that seems speciffic to the Home version. We install Pro. That might be why....